# How to render element wrappers dynamically in React Native

Tags: react-native

Let's say I have too many wrapper components A, B, C .....

Sometimes I want to render

```
    <A>
      <Text>{this.state.myText}</Text>
   </A>
```

And some other times I want to render

```
   <B>
      <Text>{this.state.myText}</Text>
   </B>
```

....

....

....

How to achieve something like this?

```
{this.bringTheRightComponentTag(this.state.wrapperComponent)}
          <Text>{this.state.myText}</Text>
{this.bringTheRightComponentClosingTag(this.state.wrapperComponent)}
```

This is a minimized example. I just need to learn the logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React actually allows you to assign the component to a variable during runtime( [Docs here](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#choosing-the-type-at-runtime)).
So you can do something like,

```
  const SelectedComponent = true ? A : B

  return (
    <SelectedComponent>
      {this.state.myText}
    </SelectedComponent>
  )
```

Comment: Saved my day. This is a game changer info for me. Thanks a lot!